# how to target element with its attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

To target and or filter the selector with it's class we can do something like this:

```
$('selector').filter('[class]="");
```

But this time I need to target the element with it's attribute or say filter the element with it attribute src something like this:

```
var srcvar = 'images/flower.jpg';
$('div img').filter('[attr]="'+srcvar+'"');// ofcourse! this is not correct way
```

I've tried like this so far:

```
var sr = $('div img').filter(function () {
            return $(this).attr('src') == srcvar;
            });
```

This is okay! But I want to get next img like this sr.next() or say I want to select the element which has attr src equals srcvar.

So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the selector this way to select the img elements with src equivalents to the value specified:

```
var $imgs = $('div img[src="' + srcvar + '"]');
```

and to get the next() element you can do:

```
 var allNextElms = $imgs.next();
```

Whether using with a single selector or a filter selector the key part you are missing is `[src="' + srcvar + '"]'` and your last filter snippet should also return exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('div img').filter('[src="'+srcvar+'"]');
```